# How do I make the process go back while counter is still counting?

Tags: python, counter

I need to find how many times it takes for my sum of border values of a randomly generated two dimensional list to equal a variable but while the counter is added the process doesn't go back.

```
import random

mylist = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]


for row in range(4):
    for col in range(4):
        index = random.randint(0, 400)
        mylist[col][row] = index
def bordervalues(mylist, a, b): 
    sum = 0

    for i in range(a): 
        for j in range(b): 
            if (i == 0): 
                sum += mylist[i][j] 
            elif (i == a-1): 
                sum += mylist[i][j] 
            elif (j == 0): 
                sum += mylist[i][j] 
            elif (j == b-1): 
                sum += mylist[i][j] 
    return sum
    sum = bordervalues(mylist, 4, 4)
counter = 0
birth = 2001
actual = sum
while actual != birth:
    counter += 1
print(counter)
```

The result of this code is an infinite loop.

Comment: Need to fix your indenting a bit there

Answer (score 0):

Try it and you'll see what I'm talking about

```
sum = bordervalues(mylist, 4, 4)
counter = 0
birth = 2001
actual = sum
while actual != birth:
   print(actual)
   counter += 1
```

Comment: That does nothing because process is stuck in lines                                                 
while actual != birth:
    counter += 1

Comment: @coz print it inside the while loop before incrementation

Comment: And there is a problem of indentation, at the level where you call the  'bordervalues'  function. It would be better if you remove the space that there is

Comment: @coz If from the start actual is different from birth it is normal that the loop does not stop because in no case the value of actual changes to become equal to that of birth